# Prestashop: notice eval()'d code [8] Array to string conversion

Tags: php, arrays, string, type-conversion, prestashop

I've been searching through this and other sites and can't solve the notice I got every time I open the back office product page.

```
Notice on line 279 in file /home/librer16/public_html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d code
[8] Array to string conversion
```

Piece of code:

```
...
else {
                //var_dump('renderTemplate', $_template->has_nocache_code, $_template->template_resource, $_template->properties['nocache_hash'], $_template->parent->properties['nocache_hash'], $_output);
              //Line 279
              if (!empty($_template->properties['nocache_hash']) && !empty($_template->parent->properties['nocache_hash'])) {
                    // replace nocache_hash
                    $_output = str_replace("{$_template->properties['nocache_hash']}", $_template->parent->properties['nocache_hash'], $_output);
                    $_template->parent->has_nocache_code = $_template->parent->has_nocache_code || $_template->has_nocache_code;
                }
            }
...
```

The website works, but this notice is very annoying.

Any suggestion to remove the notice?

Comment: Hi, Your line of code is working at my end. Can you please explain this little more or did you checked the data of "$_template" object?

Comment: Hi, I don't know how to check the data stored in "$_template". I tried it using print_r( $_template->get_template_vars() );  but got a fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the line with this one:

```
  if (is_array($_template->properties) && !empty($_template->properties['nocache_hash']) && is_array($_template->parent->properties) && !empty($_template->parent->properties['nocache_hash']))
```

Anyway, if you deactivated Debug Mode warningins won't show anymore.

Good luck.

Comment: sorry, it didn't work. Yes, I can deactivate the Debug Mode, but I'd like to get rid of errors and warning on the website. Cheers!